# Only some markers showing

Tags: leaflet

I experience a weird behavior once I upload my map to my site. One marker layer gets shown the others not. It does work fine locally, when I just open the local html file. Once uploaded, I get this: 
http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/Kisandra_map.html

The marker exists and can be clicked, but is not shown. In Firefox you can even see the frame where it should be. What baffles me though, is that it works locally but only shows the towns layer once uploaded.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
    //create map icon class
    var TaladasIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconSize:     [50, 50],
        iconAnchor:   [25, 25],
        popupAnchor:  [0, -25]
    }
});

    //define icons
    var metropolisIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/metropolis.png'}),
        cityIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/city.png'}),
        townIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/town.PNG'});
        villageIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/village.png'});

//TODO - define map marker coordinates. Pull icon coordinates from Photoshop after vertical mirror
    var yaurah          = xy(619, 1210);
    var schwarzhafen    = xy(227, 1500);

    var wolynsfurt      = xy(324, 1082);
    var khazatwurn      = xy(454, 1734);
    var khazatvallhir   = xy(733, 1715);
    var khazatmigdahl   = xy(541, 1591);
    var tannenburg      = xy(590, 1406);
    var kondeori        = xy(1529, 1331);
    var gantol          = xy(1038, 1089);
    var styria          = xy(969, 1044);
    var karamorkia      = xy(893, 998);
    var khirruku        = xy(760, 979);
    var quellburg       = xy(490, 935);

//TODO - define map marker popups

    //metropolises first
    var yaurahMarker = L.marker(     yaurah, {icon: metropolisIcon}).bindPopup('<h2>Yaurah</h2><p>Hauptstadt des Reiches</p>').bindTooltip("Yaurah");

    //cities next
    var schwarzhafenMarker = L.marker(     schwarzhafen, {icon: cityIcon}).bindPopup('<h2>Schwarzhafen</h2><p>Hauptstadt der Schnittlande</p>').bindTooltip("Yaurah");

    //towns after that
    var wolynsfurtMarker    = L.marker(     wolynsfurt, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(      'Wolynsfurt').bindTooltip("Wolynsfurt");
    var khazatwurnMarker    = L.marker(     khazatwurn, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(      'Khazat Wurn').bindTooltip("Khazat Wurn"),
        khazatvallhirMarker = L.marker(     khazatvallhir, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(   'Khazat Vallhir').bindTooltip("Khazat Vallhir"),
        khazatmigdahlMarker = L.marker(     khazatmigdahl, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(   'Khazat Migdahl').bindTooltip("Khazat Migdahl"),
        tannenburgMarker    = L.marker(     tannenburg, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(      'Tannenburg').bindTooltip("Tannenburg"),
        kondeoriMarker      = L.marker(     kondeori, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(        'Konde Ori').bindTooltip("Konde Ori"),
        gantolMarker        = L.marker(     gantol, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(          'Gantol').bindTooltip("Gantol"),
        styriaMarker        = L.marker(     styria, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(          'Styria').bindTooltip("Styria"),
        karamorkiaMarker    = L.marker(     karamorkia, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(      'Karamorkia').bindTooltip("Karamorkia"),
        khirrukuMarker      = L.marker(     khirruku, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(        'Khir Ruku').bindTooltip("Khir Ruku"),
        quellburgMarker     = L.marker(     quellburg, {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup(       'Quellburg').bindTooltip("Quellburg");

    //villages last

//TODO - group layers
    var metropolises = L.layerGroup([yaurahMarker]);
    var cities = L.layerGroup([schwarzhafenMarker]);
    var towns = L.layerGroup([wolynsfurtMarker, khazatwurnMarker, khazatvallhirMarker, khazatmigdahlMarker, tannenburgMarker, kondeoriMarker, gantolMarker, styriaMarker, karamorkiaMarker, khirrukuMarker, quellburgMarker]);
//      villages = L.layerGroup([]);


    map.addLayer(metropolises);

    //show cities only at zoom level 0
    map.on('zoomend', function() {
        var zoomlevel = map.getZoom();
            if (map.getZoom() <0){
                    map.removeLayer(cities);
            }
            else {
                    map.addLayer(cities);
                }
});

    //show towns only at zoom level 1
    map.on('zoomend', function() {
        var zoomlevel = map.getZoom();
            if (map.getZoom() <1){
                    map.removeLayer(towns);
            }
            else {
                    map.addLayer(towns);
                }
});
```

Please excuse the likely messy code, I'm new to this all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your img path is wrong `new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/metropolis.png'})`
http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/img/metropolis.png

**Edit:**
the img suffix is uppercase but in the code it is lowercase:
http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/img/metropolis.PNG http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/img/metropolis.png

Comment: I doubt it - the img directory is there and the files are in there too. Not only is the town symbol in there too and is shown, the whole background image is in the img directory. Not sure why we can't access it via browser, but I can see it in WinSCP. See here: https://imgur.com/ibkoRN8 - maps.dungeonmasterresources.com is mapped to the maps directory on the server.

Comment: change your img suffix to lowercase. http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/img/metropolis.PNG http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/img/metropolis.png then it will work

Comment: Case sensitivity, of course! *slaps forehead* Thank you! I would likely never found that on my own. Always the little things...